# Error in using External Classes in Xcode (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors

I am a beginner to iOS development, and I have been facing this problem for quite some time now..

Whenever I download an external Library/Class/Module for an iOS project from Github, etc. I get the following error in Xcode:

For example, I am trying to use the "DDBadgeViewCell" Class from github here:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a linker error. This means that you are not including the `DDBadgeViewCell` as part of your project. Make sure the `DDBadgeViewCell.m` file is part of your project and it is selected for target membership.

Select the `DDBadgeViewCell.m` file on the left side of Xcode. Using the View menu, go to Utilities and select Show File Inspector. In the right pane of Xcode, lookup for Target Membership. Make sure the checkbox is checked next to your target.

Try another build.

Comment: Actually, It's happening again, I am trying to use QuartzCore: http://i40.tinypic.com/2q2hn5e.png